# ampersand in friendly url failing with rewrite module

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, url-rewrite-module

I can do say:  `?a=1&b=r%26d` to the aspx page just fine.  The `&` in the second parameter is encoded as `%26` since `&` is reserved as a delimiter.

I downloaded and installed the *URL Rewrite Module 2.0* for IIS7.5 on 2008 R2.

I wrote a simple rule: `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` to match and rewrite the url: `Default.aspx?a={R:1}&b={R:2}`.

So, things like `1/a b` work out fine to `?a=1&b=a b`, but something like `1/a%26b` or `1/a&b` only work out to `?a=1&b=a` it seems everything is cutoff after that %26 or & at run-time.  However, in the Server Manager I can test the rewrite and nothing is cut-off in the test tool in their GUI.

Not sure what to do about this, everything I've done seemed pretty straight-forward.  So to be clear, how can I have a friendly URL that has an ampersand in it (or %26 if I have to) and have the URL Rewrite 2.0 module pass along the full parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while, but I found the answer.  The URL gets decoded before it's passed, so an extra variable is created.

Anyways, the solution was actually quite simple.  Turns out all I needed to do was adjust the Rewrite URL rule to this:

`Default.aspx?a={UrlEncode{R:1}}&b={R:2}`

The UrlEncode function will encode {R:1} correctly.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a colon after UrlEncode in the expression above. Otherwise, works great.